# JavaScript Grid in Absolute Values

Tags: javascript, grid

I'm developing a grid in javascript and need it to work in absolute mode .. No css ... because I'll use logic in another program ...
the question I have here is that I first made the items to be added without columns ... and now that I am trying to implement the columns I can not understand where I need to correct so that the items are within the same column without the left spacing ... could someone help me fix this?

thank you...

Here 2 Links ... Only Rows and My Desenv No Colums Implemented...

[This jsfiddle.net is not resolved](https://jsfiddle.net/z0tjx2qd/)

[This jsfiddle.net is Only Rows no Columns](https://jsfiddle.net/7ypfgvrt/)

Here My Code for View....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>GETTING STARTED WITH BRACKETS</title>
        <meta name="description" content="An interactive getting started guide for Brackets.">
        <style>* {Padding:0px; margin:0px;}</style>
    </head>

    <body style="background-color:darkgrey;">
        <div id="content"></div>

        <script type="application/javascript">

            var GWidth = 400;
            var GHeight = 150;
            var GBorder = 5;
            var GTop = 10;
            var GLeft = 10;
            var GRight = 10;
            var GBottom = 10;

            xGroup = "<div style='margin-top:"+GTop+"px;margin-left:"+GLeft+"px;margin-right:"+GRight+"px;margin-bottom:"+GBottom+"px;width:"+GWidth+"px;height:"+GHeight+"px;background-color:#336699;color:white;text-align:center;absolute:relative;float:left;border:"+GBorder+"px solid white;'>";

        // Baseado em TPL
        var TotalItems = 10;
        var TotalColums = 3;
        var xColum = 1;

        for(x=1;x<=TotalItems;x++)
        {
            if(xColum>TotalColums){xColum=1;}

            var MarLeft = 10;
            var MarTop = 10;
            var BoxBorder = 4;

            var MarRight = MarLeft;
            var MarBottom = MarTop;
            var BoxWidth = (GWidth-BoxBorder*2) / TotalItems - MarLeft
            var BoxHeight = GHeight - (BoxBorder*2) - MarTop

            var PosTop =0;
            var PosLeft = 0;
            var PosRight = PosLeft;
            var PosBottom = PosTop;

            var bgcolor = "D9D9D9"
             if (x % 2 == 0) {bgcolor = "e1e1e1"}

            // GBorder + Divide + BoxBorder
            PosLeft = PosLeft + (GBorder+GLeft) - (MarLeft/2) + (BoxWidth+MarLeft) * (x-1)
            PosTop = PosTop + (GBorder+GTop) - MarTop/2

            if(xColum>1){
                //PosTop = PosTop + BoxHeight + (GBorder+GTop+MarTop) /2
                PosTop = PosTop + BoxHeight*(xColum-1)+ ((GBorder+GTop+MarTop) /2) * (xColum-1)
            }

            xGroup += "<div style='top:"+PosTop+"px; left:"+PosLeft+"px; right:"+PosRight+"px; bottom:"+PosBottom+"px; margin-left:"+MarLeft+"px; margin-right:"+MarRight+"px; margin-bottom:"+MarBottom+"px; margin-top:"+MarTop+"px; width:"+BoxWidth+"px;height:"+BoxHeight+"px;background-color:#"+bgcolor+";color:white;text-align:center;position:absolute;float:left;border:"+BoxBorder+"px solid black;'></div>";    
            xColum++;
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xGroup + "</div>";
        }

</script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so, you'd want a table, with rows (tr) and columns (td)?

Comment: No... Is necessary make InnerHTML...

Comment: right, but you'd want a table with rows and columns?